# Authenticate with http headers with savon 2.3.0

Tags: ruby, wsdl, savon

I had this code in Savon v1:

```
client = Savon.client("http://www.server.com:9191/soapserver?wsdl")
service = client.request :get_authentication do
  client.http.headers["username"] = "myuser"
  client.http.headers["password"] = "mypass"
end
```

After the update to savon v2.3.0, I don't manage to retranslate. It should be something like

```
client = Savon.client do
  wsdl "http://www.shab.ch:9191/soapserver?wsdl
end
service = client.call(:get_authentication, {username: "myuser", password: "mypass"})`
```

but the line `service = client.call(...`" does not work. Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Do you get an error message, does nothing happen, does your machine crash, perhaps something else?

Comment: Also, is the code exactly as you've pasted it? The last code block isn't valid Ruby code as far as I can tell.

Comment: Correct, my last code block isn't valid and I've got no idea, how it should look. But that's my question.

Comment: Oh, okay, so you're asking how to fix the syntax errors you must be getting from that code. I've added an answer for that.

Comment: well, syntax should be ok, but also code must be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want to do is:

```
gem "savon"
require "savon", "~>2.0"
...
client = Savon.client(headers: { username: "user", password: "password"},
                      wsdl: "http://www.example.com/?wsdl",
                      log: true,
                      log_level: :debug,
                      pretty_print_xml: true
                      #, and more options here if necessary)
```

That will inject the key/values pairs into the http headers.

Comment: I get following error while using your code:
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/savon-2.3.0/lib/savon/options.rb:36:in `method_missing': Unknown local option: :headers (Savon::UnknownOptionError)

Comment: yeah, made a mistake. Difficult to test if there is no real world system to check against. Please see my edited response. It's basically a global option, not local one. So you have to provide the information when you create the client.

Comment: Thank you, exactly that was the problem. I would vote up but cant (low reputation)

Comment: I'm happy it worked out for. You can accept the answer, that would raise my reputation :-).

Answer (score 0):

That last code block of yours is missing a `"` on line #2 and has a ``` too much in the end. It should look like:

```
client = Savon.client do
  wsdl "http://www.shab.ch:9191/soapserver?wsdl"
end
service = client.call(:get_authentication, {username: "myuser", password: "mypass"})
```

to not trigger any syntax errors.

Comment: well, but this does not inject username/password into my header

Answer (score 0):

This works for me after a lot of trial and error:

```
client = Savon.client( wsdl: "http://www.server.com:9191/soapserver?wsdl", <\br>
                       headers: {'username' => 'myuser', 'password' => 'mypass'} )
service = client.call(:get_authentication)
```

So the header injection I do before calling the :get_authentication function.